# How to remove mysterious whitespace at bottom of page in CSS?

Tags: css, d3.js, bootstrap-5, whitespace

I am trying to build a simple webpage using Bootstrap and D3, but I do not know how to get rid of all the whitespace at the bottom. I would like to get rid of it.

I have tried setting the `min-height` of the `body` and `html` to 100%, but it hasn't done anything. My code is here: https://github.com/eelegiap/thesis-code/tree/main/search

```css
body {
    padding-left: 3vh;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#searchCol {
    padding-left: 6vh
}

form {
    width: 25%
}

#results {
    padding-right: 10vh;
}

#resultsContainer {
    max-height: 30%;
    overflow-y: auto
}
.result {
    padding-left: 4vh;
}
.poemResult {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#poemContainer {
    max-height: 30%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#poemMeta {
    padding-top: 10vh;
    padding-left: 15vh;
    padding-bottom: 5vh
}
#poemTxt {
    padding-left: 15vh;
    padding-bottom: 10vh;
}

.input-group {
    max-width: 75%;
    padding-bottom: 5vh
}

/* Tooltip text */
.titleTooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: #e5ffff;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;

    z-index: 1;
}

.titleTooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

.token mark {
    display: contents;
}

input,
.dropdown-toggle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchBar {
    min-height: 50px
}

#search {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" />
<!-- MDB -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mdb5/css/mdb.min.css" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Contemporary Russian Internet Poetry</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row" id="poemContainer">
          <div id="poemMeta"></div>
          <div id="poemTxt"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="searchCol">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-outline flex-fill searchBar">
              <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
              <label class="form-label" for="form1">Search by keyword(s)</label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id='search' class="btn searchBar">
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="resultsContainer">
          <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- MDB -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="mdb5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<!-- embedding JS libraries -->

<!-- d3 -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<!-- own js files -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/text.js"></script>
<script src="js/searchResults.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean, whitespace at the bottom. The bottom of the page or the bottom of a block of text??

Comment: When I serve the code on my computer and look at the inspector, the element <div class="col-sm-6"> before the #poemContainer div seems to extend twice as long as the other areas of the page which I've specified to only be screen height.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `padding-bottom: 20px;` in your body. It created the bottom padding or some spaces in the down side of your websites.

[image]

You have to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, idk why this works, but I changed the max-height variables to pixel heights instead, and this fixed the trailing whitespace problem.

Comment: You have quite a few padding properties (e.g. .input-group) set as viewport units (e.g. 5vh). This means that it's adding padding as the size of the screen increases. So when you resize the browser screen, it adds whitespace to the bottom of your elements. I'd choose another unit e.g. rem.